# How do I transfer from using state_machine to assm? Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this code written using state_machine gem but how do I make equivalent code using assm gem?

```
 state_machine :state, initial: :pending do
        after_transition on: :accept, do: :send_acceptance_email

        state :requested

        event :accept do
            transition any => :accepted
        end
    end
```

This is whats done after accepting friendship request

```
def self.request(user1, user2)
      transaction do
        friendship1 = create!(user: user1, friend: user2, state: 'pending')
        friendship2 = create!(user: user1, friend: user2, state: 'requested')

        friendship1.send_request_email
        friendship1

      end
    end


    def send_request_email
        UserNotifier.friend_requested(id).deliver
    end

    def send_acceptance_email
        UserNotifier.friend_accepted(id).deliver 
    end
```

User.rb

```
has_many :friends, through: :user_friendships,
                       conditions: { user_friendships: { state: 'accepted' } }

    has_many :pending_user_friendships, class_name: 'UserFriendship',
                                        foreign_key: :user_id,
                                        conditions: { state: 'pending' }

    has_many :pending_friends, through: :pending_user_friendships, source: :friend
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to include this line in your model

```
include AASM
```

#though i always used status as column for state machine, but you can try state as column as well which you are using. hope this wont be an issue.

```
aasm column: 'state', initial: :pending, whiny_transitions: true do
  state :requested # im not seeing any event which set this state
  state :accepted

  #if you want an to trigger request event from any state simply add this
  event :request,   after: Proc.new { send_request_email }       do transitions to: :requested end


  #if you want to trigger accepted state from any state do this
  event :accept,   after: Proc.new { send_acceptance_email }       do transitions to: :accepted end

  #if you want to trigger accepted state from only requeste state
  event :accept,   after: Proc.new { send_acceptance_email }      do transitions from: :requested,   to: :accepted  end

end
```

If you don't like exceptions and prefer a simple true or false as response, tell AASM not to be whiny:

```
:whiny_transitions => false
```

reference: https://github.com/aasm/aasm